# Testing a file's contents in VSCode TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add onto an extension in [vscode](http://code.visualstudio.com) and am now trying to write test scripts for the code I completed. I am new to TypeScript and what I have does work, but I just don't know how to open a file that I saved & closed with the command I wrote, then open the file back up and check the contents in a test case.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is older and I hope you solved your problem in the meantime, but you might try opening it using your uri or file path you saved the file to:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
function openDocument(uri: vscode.Uri|string): Promise<vscode.TextDocument> {
    if(typeof uri === "string")
        uri = vscode.Uri.parse(uri);
   return await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri as vscode.Uri);
}
```

then you can get the text on the doc:

```
let mydoc = await openDocument("file:///c:/myuser/myfolder/myfile.txt");
let text = mydoc.getText();
```